# Doctrine cant connect to database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Im running a Symfony 5.3.2 application with Doctrine-bundle 2.4.2
I have a MariaDB 10.4.4 running also in a Docker-Container.

In my Controller Im trying to use:

```
 $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
 $repo = $doctrine ->getRepository('TestBundle:User');
```

But I just got the error
`An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

I have no Idea what Im missing. Do I need a special configuration in my database?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM composer:latest AS composer
FROM php:7.4.20-apache

COPY --chown=33:33 . /srv/test
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/lib/
COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/lib/php
COPY .docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

WORKDIR /srv/test

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/test

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libzip-dev \
                zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete \
    && useradd -rm -d /home/test-s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 503 test \
    && pecl install xdebug \
    && apt install nano \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
RUN composer install
```

My Docker-Compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: test-docker
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/test
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: 'serverName=localhost'
      XDEBUG_SESSION: 'PHPSTORM'
      XDEBUG_MODE: 'debug'
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.4.4
    container_name: test_mysql
    volumes:
      - .docker/mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

Config.yml

```
#If used in an dockerized development environment just remove the comment infront of the line containing
# "parameters_docker.yml" and comment out the line above.
imports:
    - { resource: parameters_docker.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    # a hack - should be configurable under jms_serializer, but the property_naming.id
    # doesn't seem to be taken into account at all.
    jms_serializer.camel_case_naming_strategy.class: JMS\Serializer\Naming\IdenticalPropertyNamingStrategy
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['php', 'twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: return
        connections:
            default:
                schema_filter: ~^(?!view_)~
            user:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
          # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
          #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
          #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
          #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
          #   3. Uncomment next line:
          #     path:     "%database_path%"
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        default_entity_manager: return
        entity_managers:
            user:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: return
                mappings:
                    TestBundle:
                        type:     "annotation"
                        dir:      "Entity/User"
                        prefix:   "TestBundle\\Entity\\User"
```

parameters_docker.yml

```
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     3306
    database_name:     symfony_rest
    database_user:     root
    database_password: password
```

Comment: can you please share your env file/config?

Comment: I added the config

Comment: try replacing database_host *127.0.0.1* by your DB's Docker container name *test_mysql*. with docker you're in your own "network" and not on local host anymore. you might be required your adjust your port to 13306 as well. so your connection issue is there.

Comment: changed it, but it doesn´t made any difference

Comment: try using `mysql` for database_host and 3306 for database_port

Comment: tried every combination. Looks like the error isnt there

Comment: is the database container actually running? `docker ps`

Comment: the database container is running. I can also connect via DataGrip etc.